# Error while publishing web app to azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-hub

I get this error when i publish my webapp. Any idea why and how can i solve it?

I was able to publish it properly but then i deleted the webapp in azure and then tried to publish it again. Got this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Just delete browser cookies.**

I created web app (1st time) --> it saved some cookies for authentication
deleted the webapp from azure -->> cookie still saved on browser
Created web app again, cookie did not get updated so there was this error.

Just delete browser cookies and it should solve this error.